# How to save remainig elements from List to the Stack?

Tags: c#, list, stack

Does anybody know how to save remaining elements from List lst to the Stack st?

I've tried if(!new_list.Contains) but it showed an error, I know that i am definitely missing something or just doing the wrong thing. I am new to c# so sorry if this is a dumb question

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();

Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    lst.Add(rnd.Next(1, 20));
}

List<int> new_lst = lst.FindAll(x => x >= 7 && x <= 12);

Console.WriteLine("");
foreach (int a in new_lst)
{
    Console.Write($"{a} "); 
}

Stack<int> st = new Stack<int>();

foreach (int a in lst)
{
    if ("code")
    {
         adding remaining elements (that didn't go to new_lst) from lst to st
    }
}
```

I expect numbers that are greater than 12 and less than 7

Comment: Here's a hint: don't rely on FindAll. Loop through the lst and add things to new_lst if they belong there, or the stack if they don't.

Comment: You can also use `Enumerable.Range` to select random items into your list, shortening that code to a single line: `List<int> lst = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => rnd.Next(1, 20)).ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a condition to your `lst` list to filter out items that are contained in `new_lst`:

```
foreach (int a in lst.Where(item => !new_lst.Contains(item)))
{
    st.Push(a);
}
```

---

That being said, it would be faster to only iterate over the items once and add them to both the full list and then to either the new list or the stack (depending on the value):

```
Random rnd = new Random();

List<int> lst = new List<int>();
List<int> new_lst = new List<int>();
Stack<int> st = new Stack<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var thisItem = rnd.Next(1, 20);

    lst.Add(thisItem);

    if (thisItem >= 7 && thisItem <= 12)
    {
        new_lst.Add(thisItem);
    }
    else
    {
        st.Push(thisItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be just add items to one or another while walking through the list:

```
foreach (int x in lst)
{
    if (x >= 7 && x <= 12)
         new_lst.add(x);
    else
         st.Push(a);

}
```

If you want to go fancier route I'd save condition in and select items to list/stack with opposite condition:

```
   Func<int,bool> filter = x => x >= 7 && x <= 12;
   var new_lst = lst.Where(filter).ToList();
   var st = new Stack<int>(lst.Where(x=> !filter(x));
```